# Do UK or US based literary agents accept (unpublished) manuscripts in a foreign language?

Tags: translation, agent, submitting-work

Do UK or US based literary agents accept (unpublished) manuscripts in a foreign language?

For example the author could provide a rough translation of the whole text and himself pay for a literary translation of the first pages, so the agent could judge the story as well as the writing.

Is such a thing heard of?

Answer (score 2):

I inquired with a US agency and they replied that:

- **they do accept manuscripts that are translated into English**
- if they are interested in the project after reading the short summary in the query letter, they will request a sample of three chapters which **need to be a professional translation**, so they can judge the work's true potential; a rough translation will not suffice